# How to fix "unzip: Unrecognized archive format" in FreeBSD?

Tags: ssh, freebsd, scp, zip

I try to unzip a folder that I copied to FreeBSD from another machine through SSH/SCP.
However, I keep getting the error `unzip: Unrecognized archive format` which to me does not make sense in this case.

Why do I get this error, and how do I fix it?

#### Extra information

```
$ ls
sw-ui-server.zip
$ unzip
Usage: unzip [-aCcfjLlnopqtuvyZ1] [-d dir] [-x pattern] [-P password] zipfile
$ unzip sw-ui-server.zip
unzip: Unrecognized archive format
```

As you can see above, I have ensured that `unzip` is installed.

I also tried to check what formats `unzip` supports, but considering it's called "unzip", I reckon `.zip` files *should* be supported.

Answer (score 0):

There may be several answers to this issue, but I will share what the problem was in my case.

The ZIP file I tried to unzip **turned out to be empty**.

I discovered this by checking the file type:

```
$ file [filename]
[filename].zip: empty
```

and the file size

```
$ ls -lh
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0B Nov 8 09:08 [filename].zip
```

The solution was to perform the copying again, and ensuring that the file was no longer empty by re-running `ls -lh`

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that on FreeBSD you can use `tar` to extract all kinds of archives thanks to [libarchive(3)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?libarchive). Very often you don't need an additional tooling from outside the base system.